# react project from codepen fails to run locally

Tags: codepen

I have built a recipe box app using react,which lets users add and delete recipes.Now,my code runs perfectly on code pen but,when i run it locally i get the error. I have used export feature of code pen to download the project and run it locally.If someone could point what error am i committing,that would be really helpful.
[link to my pen](https://codepen.io/renx777/pen/ypBRmP)

Error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of null
    at t.render (index.js:182)
    at c._renderValidatedComponentWithoutOwnerOrContext (react.min.js:13)
    at c._renderValidatedComponent (react.min.js:13)
    at c.mountComponent (react.min.js:13)
    at Object.mountComponent (react.min.js:14)
    at mountChildren (react.min.js:14)
    at m._createContentMarkup (react.min.js:13)
    at mountComponent (react.min.js:13)
    at Object.mountComponent (react.min.js:14)
    at c.mountComponent (react.min.js:13)
```

here is my code

```
var Modal = ReactBootstrap.Modal;
var Accordion = ReactBootstrap.Accordion;
var Button = ReactBootstrap.Button;
var Popover = ReactBootstrap.Popover;
var Tooltip = ReactBootstrap.Tootip;
var FormGroup = ReactBootstrap.FormGroup;
var Input = ReactBootstrap.Input;
var Textarea = ReactBootstrap.TextArea;
var FormControl = ReactBootstrap.FormControl;
var ListGroup = ReactBootstrap.ListGroup,
    ListGroupItem = ReactBootstrap.ListGroupItem;
var Panel = ReactBootstrap.Panel;

const AddModal = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return { showModal: false };
  },

  close() {
    this.setState({ showModal: false });
  },

  open() {
    this.setState({ showModal: true });
  },

  render() {


    return (
      <div>
        <Button
          bsStyle={this.props.bStyle}
          bsSize={this.props.bSize}
          onClick={this.open}
          >
          {this.props.name}
        </Button>

        <Modal show={this.state.showModal} onHide={this.close}>
          <Modal.Header closeButton>
            <Modal.Title>{this.props.title}</Modal.Title>
          </Modal.Header>
          <Modal.Body>
            <Input
              id="name"
              type="text"
              label="Recipe"
              placeholder="Recipe Name"
               defaultValue={this.props.rvalue}
              />
            <Input
              id="ingri"
              type="textarea"
              label="Ingredients"
              placeholder="Enter Ingredients,Separated,By Commas"
              defaultValue={this.props.ivalue}
              />
          </Modal.Body>
          <Modal.Footer>
            <Button id="blue" bsStyle="primary" data-key={this.props.keys} onClick={this.props.onClick}>
              {this.props.title}
            </Button>
            <Button onClick={this.close}>Close</Button>
          </Modal.Footer>
        </Modal>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

const RecipeBox = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
//  get locally stored recipe values
    var local_recipes=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("recipes"))
//     if no recipes set locally,use default values
    if(local_recipes=="null" || local_recipes.length==0){
        var default_recipes=[
        {
          name: "Pumpkin Pie",
          ingredients: [
            "Pumpkin Puree",
            "Sweetened Condensed Milk",
            "Eggs",
            "Pumpkin Pie Spice",
            "Pie Crust"
          ]
        },
        {
          name: "Spaghetti",
          ingredients: ["Noodles", "Tomato Sauce", "(Optional) Meatballs"]
        },
        {
          name: "Onion Pie",
          ingredients: ["Onion", "Pie Crust", "Sounds Yummy right?"]
        }
      ]
    localStorage.setItem("recipes",JSON.stringify(default_recipes) );
      local_recipes=default_recipes
    }

    return {
      recipes: local_recipes
    };
  },

  addRecipe(x) {
    const recipe = {};
    recipe.name = $("#name").val();
    recipe.ingredients = $("#ingri")
      .val()
      .split(",");

    const newState = this.state.recipes;
    newState.push(recipe);
//     update local storage
     localStorage.setItem("recipes",JSON.stringify(newState) );
//     update state
    this.setState({
      recipes: newState
    });
  },
  editRecipe(e){
    const orecipe = {};
    orecipe.name = $("#name").val();
    orecipe.ingredients = $("#ingri")
      .val()
      .split(",");




  const i=e.target.attributes.getNamedItem("data-key").value
  const editedRecipe=this.state.recipes;
   editedRecipe[i].name=orecipe.name
    editedRecipe[i].ingredients=orecipe.ingredients
//     update local storage with edited recipes
    localStorage.setItem("recipes",JSON.stringify(editedRecipe) );
   this.setState({
     recipes:editedRecipe
   }) 
  },

  delete(e){
    const i = e.target.attributes.getNamedItem("data-key").value;
    const deletedRecipe = this.state.recipes;

    deletedRecipe.splice(i,1)
//     update local storage with new recipe list after deleteion
    localStorage.setItem("recipes",JSON.stringify(deletedRecipe) );
    this.setState({
      recipes: deletedRecipe
    });

  },



  render() {
    return (
      <div>

        <RecipeBars recipes={this.state.recipes} editRecipe={this.editRecipe} delete={this.delete} onClick={this.addRecipe} />
        <AddModal
          onClick={this.addRecipe}
          title="Add a Recipe"
          name="Add Recipe"
          bSize="large"
          bStyle="primary"
          />
      </div>
    );
  }
});

const RecipeBars = React.createClass({

  render() {
    const recipes = this.props.recipes;

    //error happens here,recipe is just a variable for map function,which shouldnt be giving error 
    const bars = recipes.map((recipe, i) => {
      var igrid = recipe.ingredients.map((val, i) => {
        return <ListGroupItem>{val}</ListGroupItem>;
      });
      var hstyle = { "text-align": "center" };
      var bstyle = { "margin-right": "5px", float: "right", display: "inline" };

      return (
        <Panel eventKey={i}   bsStyle="success" collapsible header={recipe.name}>
          <h4 style={hstyle}>Ingredients</h4>
          <ListGroup fill>{igrid}</ListGroup>
          <Button data-key={i} style={bstyle} onClick={this.props.delete} bsSize="small" bsStyle="danger">
            delete
          </Button>

          <AddModal
            title="Edit Recipe"
            onClick={this.props.editRecipe}
            keys={i}
            name="Edit"
            bSize="small"
            bStyle="info"
            rvalue={recipe.name}
            ivalue={recipe.ingredients.join(',')}
            />
        </Panel>
      );
    });

    return <div><Accordion onSelect={this.pclick}>{bars}< /Accordion></div>;
  }
});

// ReactDOM.render(<AddModal title="Add a Recipe" name="Add Recipe" bSize="large" bStyle="primary"/>,document.getElementById('app'))

ReactDOM.render(<RecipeBox />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

Comment: I get the same error in your codepen. clear your localstorage and check it out

Comment: ya mate,i was doing it wrong,my code to setup local storage had bug...thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

It was error from my end,i was not setting up local storage in a proper way,here is how i corrected it
[link to working pen](https://codepen.io/renx777/pen/ypBRmP?editors=0010)

```
//  get locally stored recipe values
    var local_recipes=localStorage.getItem("recipes");
//     check if recipes is defined in local storage
  if(typeof local_recipes !== 'undefined' && local_recipes !== null){
//     if recipe is stored in local storage
    var local_recipes=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("recipes"))

    }else{

//       if recipe is not stored in local storage
      var default_recipes=[
        {
          name: "Pumpkin Pie",
          ingredients: [
            "Pumpkin Puree",
            "Sweetened Condensed Milk",
            "Eggs",
            "Pumpkin Pie Spice",
            "Pie Crust"
          ]
        },
        {
          name: "Spaghetti",
          ingredients: ["Noodles", "Tomato Sauce", "(Optional) Meatballs"]
        },
        {
          name: "Onion Pie",
          ingredients: ["Onion", "Pie Crust", "Sounds Yummy right?"]
        }
      ]
    localStorage.setItem("recipes",JSON.stringify(default_recipes) );
      local_recipes=default_recipes

    }
```